# Save search criteria per user and show on custom user page

Tags: pages, search, users

I have a property website with a custom search form for minimum and maximum square feet.

A registered user executes a search with a min(i.e. 150 sqft) and max(i.e. 300 sqft) select option value.

I managed already to store inside cookies the min and max values.

Then the user is able to click on a "save this search" button.

I would like to save those values inside the database and show them on each user's profile page (that I already created).

When the user goes to its profile page I'd like to have a list of all the saved searches.

I hope this makes sense.

Ideally the custom user page would look like this:

Saved Search 1: 150sq ft - 300 sq ft

Saved Search 2: 500sq ft - 800 sq ft

...

Is this possible? How would I do this?

I'm quite new at customising WordPress templates, I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those users have accounts on your site (are subscribers, authors, or some other role), you can add custom fields to their profiles. The easiest way is to use a plugin, like Advanced Custom Fields (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

The fields would be available in their profile pages, and you can add, and use in any template.

I would give you code examples, but their site seems to be down... I'll try to update the answer once it's up again.

**Update**: ACF could take care of creating the fields, and displaying them in the user profile page, and you can use add_user_meta to save them:

```
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_field_name', $search);
```

If you don't want to use ACF, you can display the fields in the profile with custom code. Deleting the searches would be a bit harder, though, but doable.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure ACF would help me. Everything needs to be done front end side: a registered user executes a search with a min(i.e. 150 sqft) and max(i.e. 300 sqft) select option value. I managed already to store inside cookies the min and max values. Then the user is able to click on a "save this search" button. I would like to save those values inside the database and show them on each user's profile page (that I already created). When the user goes to its profile page I'd like to have a list of all the saved searches. I hope this makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Sumup:

Create a new post & save the search info as post meta-data, then reference it later by the post-id.

#### [Create custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

#### Learn to [Save post meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_meta)

#### Use [wp_insert_post to save post & meta when search saved](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post)

#### Output in templates using conventional loops

This gives us a backend solution, that could tie-in to the data you've mentioned saving, a front-end solution might consist of adding the data to `window.localStorage` for later lookup & pre-population into the form inputs.